# Requirejs + text plugin + sugar syntax + almond.js

Tags: requirejs, almond

I'm using the sugar syntax to load templates into my views:

```
...
var template = require('text!templates/toolbar/toolbar.html')
```

Everything works fine, but when I run the r.js optimizer I get the error

```
TypeError: Object function () {
        //A version of a require function that passes a moduleName
        //value for items that may need to
        //look up paths relative to the moduleName
        return req.apply(undef, aps.call(arguments, 0).concat([relName, forceSync]));
    } has no method 'toUrl'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  Running into the same problem myself.

Comment: yeah I found it, but cannot remember what, please give me some time :)

Comment: Take a look at this repo: https://github.com/zimok/mocha-expect-require where I managed to make Require.js work with sugar syntax. Anyway I'm still not sure wether it'll run after r.js optimization. Let me dive deeply.

Comment: I figured out my problem, in my case it was actually that require was attempting to make a request for a network resource, which almond does not support.  Thanks for taking a look though!